# Gem Path Issue: RubyGems looking in the wrong place

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I require certain gems, some of them work and some of them don't work. They seem to install find and I can do a gem list and they are there. However, when I try to run them in Irb or run my ruby programs from the terminal I get the following:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- sanitize

/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `gem_original_require'
```

And so I followed the guide on RubyGems and everything seems fine:

```
noahclark$ gem list sanitize
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
sanitize (2.0.3)


noahclark$ ruby -rubygems -e 'require "sanitize"'
noahclark$ 

noahclark$ which ruby
/opt/local/bin/ruby
noahclark$  gem env | grep 'RUBY EXECUTABLE'
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/local/bin/ruby
```

So then I tried:

```
noahclark$ which gem
/opt/local/bin/gem

noahclark$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10
- RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-darwin10]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/local/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/local/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
   - x86-darwin-10
 - GEM PATHS:
    - /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
    - /Users/noahclark/.gem/ruby/1.8
 - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
    - :benchmark => false
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - REMOTE SOURCES:
    - http://rubygems.org/
```

You can see that which gem and gem environment are looking at two separate directories. I hunted around for a fix and I could only find something that suggested adding export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin/gem to my .bashrc file. This did not fix it.

How should I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the path in your error message, your irb and apps are probably using the default system ruby.

What does `which irb` show?
And what is the commandline you use to run your apps?

You may need to adjust the shebang line (the first line which starts with "#!") of your scripts to use /opt/local/bin/ruby.

Comment: which irb results in /opt/local/bin/irb

Comment: @noahclark What error does this show (if any): `irb -rubygems -r sanitize`

Comment: Weird, I ran that it worked. I had restarted my computer to make sure that .bashrc was loaded, but that didn't help. Not sure what I did or why it works now but it does! Thanks!

Comment: I just tried doing it and it was fixed before and it now flipped back so I'm having issues even though I haven't changed anything. Any ideas?

Comment: @noah Do you mean `irb -rubygems -r sanitize` is failing? What's the error? Are you using a different terminal session than you did when it succeeded? Did you prepend /opt/local/bin (not /opt/local/bin/gem) to your PATH in .bashrc and restart the term session?

Comment: @noah i should also ask, what does `echo $PATH` return in the terminal prompt?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3450/discussion-between-kelvin-and-noahclark)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your .bashrc?

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin/gem:$PATH
```

That gives the your new gem path the first crack rather than the current, incorrect default.

Comment: @noahclark How did you install ruby? If you used macports, it should've changed your ~/.profile so "/opt/local/bin" was first. You do have to exit any terminal session and open new ones - if you didn't, you might've installed some gems under the system ruby.